# Extraer datos y separarlos por un párrafo

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente archivo javascript

```
let objUno = {
    Traumatologia: [
      {
          HORA: "8:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA PAZ ALTUZARRA",
          PACIENTE: "PAULA SANCHEZ",
          RUT: "15554774-5",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "10:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "RAUL ARAYA",
          PACIENTE: "ANGÉLICA NAVAS",
          RUT: "15444147-9",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "10:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA ARRIAGADA",
          PACIENTE: "ANA KLAPP",
          RUT: "17879423-9",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "ALEJANDRO BADILLA",
          PACIENTE: "FELIPE MARDONES",
          RUT: "1547423-6",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "CECILIA BUDNIK",
          PACIENTE: "DIEGO MARRE",
          RUT: "16554741-K",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "12:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "ARTURO CAVAGNARO",
          PACIENTE: "CECILIA MENDEZ",
          RUT: "9747535-8",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "12:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "ANDRES KANACRI",
          PACIENTE: "MARCIAL SUAZO",
          RUT: "11254785-5",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      }
    ],
    
    }

    let clientesUno = objUno.Traumatologia;
    for(item of clientesUno){
       let textUno = `<p>${item.HORA}, ${item.ESPECIALISTA}, ${item.PACIENTE}</p>`
       document.getElementById("traumatologia").innerHTML+=textUno;
    }
    
let obj = {
    Radiologia: [
         {
              HORA: "11:00",
              ESPECIALISTA: "IGNACIO SCHULZ",
              PACIENTE: "FRANCISCA ROJAS",
              RUT: "9878782-1",
              PREVISION: "FONASA"
         },
         {
             HORA: "11:30",
             ESPECIALISTA: "FEDERICO SUBERCASEAUX",
             PACIENTE: "PAMELA ESTRADA",
             RUT: "15345241-3",
             PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
         },
         {
             HORA: "15:00",
             ESPECIALISTA: "FERNANDO WURTHZ",
             PACIENTE: "ARMANDO LUNA",
             RUT: "16445345-9",
             PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
         },
         {
             HORA: "15:30",
             ESPECIALISTA: "ANA MARIA GODOY",
             PACIENTE: "MANUEL GODOY",
             RUT: "17666419-0",
             PREVISION: "FONASA"
         },
         {
             HORA: "16:00",
             ESPECIALISTA: "PATRICIA SUAZO",
             PACIENTE: "RAMON ULLOA",
             RUT: "14989389-K",
             PREVISION: "FONASA"
         }
     ],
   }

   let clientesDos = obj.Radiologia;
   for(item of clientesDos){
      let textDos = `<p>${item.HORA}, ${item.ESPECIALISTA}, ${item.PACIENTE}</p>`
      document.getElementById("radiologia").innerHTML+=textDos;
   }

let objDos = {
    Dental: [
      {
          HORA: "8:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "ANDREA ZUÑIGA",
          PACIENTE: "MARCELA RETAMAL",
          RUT: "11123425-6",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA PIA ZAÑARTU",
          PACIENTE: "ANGEL MUÑOZ",
          RUT: "9878789-2",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "SCARLETT WITTING",
          PACIENTE: "MARIO KAST",
          RUT: "7998789-5",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "13:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "FRANCISCO VON TEUBER",
          PACIENTE: "KARIN FERNANDEZ",
          RUT: "18887662-K",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "13:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "EDUARDO VIÑUELA",
          PACIENTE: "HUGO SANCHEZ",
          RUT: "17665461-4",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "14:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "RAQUEL VILLASECA",
          PACIENTE: "ANA SEPULVEDA",
          RUT: "14441281-0",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      }
    ]
    }
    let clientes = objDos.Dental;
for(item of clientes){
   let text = `<p>${item.HORA}, ${item.ESPECIALISTA}, ${item.PACIENTE}</p>`
   document.getElementById("consultantes").innerHTML+=text;
}
```

Renderiza a la perfección. Lo que necesito es separar por un párrafo los datos de radiologia, luego por otro parrafo los datos de traumatologia y luego por un párrafo estos de los últimos datos que se imprimen en la página web.
La idea es que tengo tres arrays formados de objetos , los recorro con el codigo que poseo y extraigo cierta información . Lo que necesito es separar los grupos por un párrafo, esto es los pacientes de traumatologia queden separardos por un párrafo de los pacientes de radiologia y estos a su vez por un parrafo de los pacientes de dental . Intruje el código
document.write(

) pero me borra la otra información.
También probé agregando
document.getElementsByClassName(".trauma").innerHTML=

con la respectiva clase en el documento html, pero no dio resultado.
Entonces quiero ver qué codigo puede servir para este caso.

Comment: Gracias por tu colaboración. No puedo visualizar la información en el navegador . Este es el documento html que tengo

Comment: Documento html es ;<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="consultantes"></div>
    
    <script src="arreglos-4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuevamente un gusto ayudarte con tu código, esta vez tienes mas de un objeto, pero como todos los objetos son sobre consultas medicas de distintas especialidades ¿Porque no ponerlos todos en un mismo objeto, que cada propiedad sea un nombre de especialidad y su contenido las consultas? de esta manera tendrás un solo objeto al que iterar ademas esto facilita hacer un salto de linea entre consultas, el código quedaría así:

```
let objMedico = {
    Dental: [
      {
          HORA: "8:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "ANDREA ZUÑIGA",
          PACIENTE: "MARCELA RETAMAL",
          RUT: "11123425-6",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA PIA ZAÑARTU",
          PACIENTE: "ANGEL MUÑOZ",
          RUT: "9878789-2",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "SCARLETT WITTING",
          PACIENTE: "MARIO KAST",
          RUT: "7998789-5",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "13:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "FRANCISCO VON TEUBER",
          PACIENTE: "KARIN FERNANDEZ",
          RUT: "18887662-K",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "13:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "EDUARDO VIÑUELA",
          PACIENTE: "HUGO SANCHEZ",
          RUT: "17665461-4",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "14:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "RAQUEL VILLASECA",
          PACIENTE: "ANA SEPULVEDA",
          RUT: "14441281-0",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      }
    ],
    Radiologia: [
         {
              HORA: "11:00",
              ESPECIALISTA: "IGNACIO SCHULZ",
              PACIENTE: "FRANCISCA ROJAS",
              RUT: "9878782-1",
              PREVISION: "FONASA"
         },
         {
             HORA: "11:30",
             ESPECIALISTA: "FEDERICO SUBERCASEAUX",
             PACIENTE: "PAMELA ESTRADA",
             RUT: "15345241-3",
             PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
         },
         {
             HORA: "15:00",
             ESPECIALISTA: "FERNANDO WURTHZ",
             PACIENTE: "ARMANDO LUNA",
             RUT: "16445345-9",
             PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
         },
         {
             HORA: "15:30",
             ESPECIALISTA: "ANA MARIA GODOY",
             PACIENTE: "MANUEL GODOY",
             RUT: "17666419-0",
             PREVISION: "FONASA"
         },
         {
             HORA: "16:00",
             ESPECIALISTA: "PATRICIA SUAZO",
             PACIENTE: "RAMON ULLOA",
             RUT: "14989389-K",
             PREVISION: "FONASA"
         }
     ],
     Traumatologia: [
      {
          HORA: "8:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA PAZ ALTUZARRA",
          PACIENTE: "PAULA SANCHEZ",
          RUT: "15554774-5",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "10:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "RAUL ARAYA",
          PACIENTE: "ANGÉLICA NAVAS",
          RUT: "15444147-9",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "10:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA ARRIAGADA",
          PACIENTE: "ANA KLAPP",
          RUT: "17879423-9",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "ALEJANDRO BADILLA",
          PACIENTE: "FELIPE MARDONES",
          RUT: "1547423-6",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "CECILIA BUDNIK",
          PACIENTE: "DIEGO MARRE",
          RUT: "16554741-K",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "12:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "ARTURO CAVAGNARO",
          PACIENTE: "CECILIA MENDEZ",
          RUT: "9747535-8",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "12:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "ANDRES KANACRI",
          PACIENTE: "MARCIAL SUAZO",
          RUT: "11254785-5",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      }
    ]
    }

for (const tipoConsulta in objMedico){  //itero por los nombres de las propiedades
  const consultantes = document.getElementById("consultantes"); //esto solo es para no repetirlo a cada momento jajaja
  consultantes.innerHTML+=tipoConsulta; //agregar el nombre de la especialidad
  for (const consulta of objMedico[tipoConsulta]){ //itera en la lista dada la especialidad(tipoConsulta)
    let textoConsulta = `<p>${consulta.HORA}, ${consulta.ESPECIALISTA}, ${consulta.PACIENTE}</p>`; //la misma linea que viene en tu codigo pero con distinto nombre de variable
    consultantes.innerHTML+=textoConsulta; 
  }
  consultantes.innerHTML+="</br>"; //esto hará un salto de linea entre especialidades
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias . Había escrito mal la referencia al archivo js . Puse arreglos-4.js y era arreglo-4.js.